# UICollectionViewCell's UiTextField, overlapping in UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to design a multistep sign-up menu. For this purpose I am using UICollectionViewController with screen size cells. In these cells, I have a UITextView to ask questions and a UITextField to collect the answers. I also have a Page object for passing in information from uicollectionviewcontroller upon setting. 
The problem I'm having now is that after every 3rd page my textField input from 3 pages ago repeats, instead of showing the placeholder. I have noticed yet another problem, the cells seem to be instantiating just 3 times, and not 6 times for how many pages I have. The instantiation order is very odd too. At first it does it once, then upon button click, twice more, then never again.
How can fix this, I am really struggling with this and I have no idea what's going wrong.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class OnboardingPageViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("made a page")
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    var oboardingPage = NewOnboardingPage() {
        didSet{
            reload()
        }
    }

    private var questionTextField: UITextView = {
        var q = UITextView()
        q.textColor = UIColor.white
        q.textAlignment = .left
        q.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 25)
        q.isEditable = true
        q.isScrollEnabled = false
        q.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        q.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        print("made aquestion field")
        return q
    }()

    private var answerField : CustomTextField = {
        let tf = CustomTextField.nameField
        print("made an answer field")
        return tf
    }()

    private func setupView(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        addSubview(questionTextField)
        questionTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true
        questionTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        questionTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.90).isActive = true
        questionTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true

        addSubview(answerField)
        answerField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: questionTextField.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
        answerField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        answerField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.90).isActive = true
        answerField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true
    }

    private func reload(){
        questionTextField.text = oboardingPage.question
        answerField.placeholder = oboardingPage.answerField
    }
}

class NewOnboardingPage {
    var question : String?
    var answerField : String?
}


import UIKit

class SignUpController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    private let cellId = "cellId"
    private var pages = [NewOnboardingPage]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super .viewDidLoad()
        setupSignUpControllerView()
        addPages()
    }

    private  func addPages(){
        let namePage = NewOnboardingPage()
        namePage.question = "What's your name?"
        namePage.answerField = "What's your name?"
        pages.append(namePage)

        let birthDayPage = NewOnboardingPage()
        birthDayPage.question = "When's your birthdate?"
        birthDayPage.answerField = "When's your birthdate?"
        pages.append(birthDayPage)

        let userNamePage = NewOnboardingPage()
        userNamePage.question = "Choose a user name."
        userNamePage.answerField = "Choose a user name."
        pages.append(userNamePage)

        let passWordPage = NewOnboardingPage()
        passWordPage.question = "Set a password"
        passWordPage.answerField = "Set a password"
        pages.append(passWordPage)

        let emailAuthPage = NewOnboardingPage()
        emailAuthPage.question = "What's your email?"
        emailAuthPage.answerField = "What's your email?"
        pages.append(emailAuthPage)

        let phoneNumberPage = NewOnboardingPage()
        phoneNumberPage.question = "What's your phone number?"
        phoneNumberPage.answerField = "What's your phone number?"
        pages.append(phoneNumberPage)
    }

    private func setupSignUpControllerView(){
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(OnboardingPageViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = true

        if let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        }

        view.addSubview(nextButton)
        nextButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 400).isActive = true
        nextButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    }

    private let nextButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.RED
        button.setTitle("next", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 25)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(turnNextPage), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc private func turnNextPage() {
        let visibleItems: NSArray = collectionView?.indexPathsForVisibleItems as! NSArray
        let currentItem: IndexPath = visibleItems.object(at: 0) as! IndexPath
        let nextItem: IndexPath = IndexPath(item: currentItem.item + 1, section: 0)
        if nextItem.row < pages.count {
            collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: nextItem, at: .left, animated: true)
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! OnboardingPageViewCell
        cell.oboardingPage = pages[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }

}


import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))

        self.allowsEditingTextAttributes = false
        self.autocorrectionType = .no

        self.tintColor = UIColor.RED
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }


    override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        editingChanged(self)
    }

    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return }
        textField.text = String(text.prefix(30))
    }

    override func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [Any] {
        return []
    }

    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if action == #selector(paste(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(cut(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(copy(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(select(_:)) ||
            action == #selector(selectAll(_:)){
            return false
        }
        return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
    }

}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! OnboardingPageViewCell
        cell.answerField.text = nil
        cell.oboardingPage = pages[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- **textFeild** showing same data instead of **placeholder** bacause of cell dequeuing so you must hook these properties and clear their content in **cellForRowAt**

2- Instantiation is 3 not 6 aslo cell dequeuing

Solve:

Add two properties to your model **NewOnboardingPage** name them currentQuestion and currentAnswer and as the user inputs and scroll to next page save them in the modelarray that you should make global to be accessed indside cell and outside set these values to the **textfeild** and **textView** as you scroll in **cellForRowAt**

Comment: you mean cellForItemAt? so like this right, (edited last)? that helps, thanks. I was not aware of dequeuing. But the thing is, now my previous data is deleted so if the user decides to swipe back and look at what was typed in, it's all gone. how do I make it show again?

Comment: when user clicks next page get the current content of the textfeild and textview and store in the corresponding index of the model array and when he clicks back reload the table

Comment: btw, how come everything else gets dequeued, but the textField? after all, I am using let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! OnboardingPageViewCell

Comment: you might be refreshing  it's placeholder in **cellForRowAt**